# None found into a regex with python

Tags: python, regex, nonetype

I'm trying to find expressions beginning by `#number`
into file with regex in Python 3.
File is something like:

```
#123= toto(ikpm,guio,gyio)
#126= tutu(kop,cfyg,jipo)
#246= toto(gyui,rtf,kjoip)
...
```

And python code:

```
LineRe = re.compile('^#([0-9]+)= .+$')
with open(path,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "toto" in line:
            lre = LineRe.fullmatch(line)
            print(lre)
            if not lre is None:
                number = lre.group(1)
                print(lre)
                print(number)
```

My regex `^#([0-9]+)= .+$` seems ok with [Test RegEx](https://regexr.com/) but my code prints always 'None'...
What is wrong, please?

Comment: Are there `toto` substrings in your expected matches? You might be testing with `^#([0-9]+)= .+$` at regexr and you are not checking for `toto` in the pattern. Please show the file contents.

Comment: Your regex works fine on my tests.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: file added on edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about `fullmatch()` so when I tried `search()` or `match()`, it worked well

```
LineRe = re.compile('^#([0-9]+)= .+$')
with open(path,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "toto" in line:
            lre = LineRe.search(line)
            print(lre)
            if not lre is None:
                number = lre.group(1)
                print(lre)
                print(number)
```

You can also use `match()`

import re

```
LineRe = re.compile('#([0-9]+)= .+')
with open(path,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "toto" in line:
            lre = LineRe.match(line)
            print(lre)
            if not lre is None:
                number = lre.group(1)
                print(lre)
                print(number)
```

OUTPUT ::

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 26), match='#123= toto(ikpm,guio,gyio)'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 26), match='#123= toto(ikpm,guio,gyio)'>
123
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 26), match='#246= toto(gyui,rtf,kjoip)'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 26), match='#246= toto(gyui,rtf,kjoip)'>
246
```

From @Eamonn Kenny 's answer :

> You just forgot to `rstrip()` your line before running `fullmatch()`
>   on it. The hint of this is in the comment of seer.The. He/She said
>   that it worked fine for them, so they are obviously using only one
>   line of text or a windows machine.
>
> ```
> lre = LineRe.fullmatch(line.rstrip())
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's ok, I love this site :)

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot to rstrip your line before running fullmatch on it. The hint of this is in the comment of seer.The. He/She said that it worked fine for them, so they are obviously using only one line of text or a windows machine.

```
lre = LineRe.fullmatch(line.rstrip())
```

Your code is otherwise perfect.